# How to print a meaningful firebase-dart exception

Tags: firebase, exception, flutter, dart

I can't get a meaningful exception error printed out to console. I get only `[object Object]`

```
@TestOn('browser')
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

import 'package:workshop_participant_flutter/firebase_config.dart' as my_config;

void main() {
  test('too big images cant be uploaded', () async {
    App app;
    app = my_config.initFirebase();
    final ref = app.storage().ref('/storageTest/test.file');
    final image = File('./too_big_file.png');
    try {
      await ref.put(image).future;
    } on IOException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      print(e);
    }
  });
}
```

I'm loading up an image to Firebase Storage and it fails because I have set the rules to reject all files bigger than x bytes. This is the wanted behaviour.

All other tests work fine. So the setup and configuration is OK. My problem now is, that I want to learn, what error message I get. I want to catch that exception and handle it.

I hope somebody has stumbled over the same phenomena and can advise me here.

In case you want to run the test code above you are going to need this file as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Upload Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/test/dart.js"></script>
    <link rel="x-dart-test" href="upload_test.dart" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm now suspecting, that this is because the firebase library is "wrapped" java script and dart doesn't expose the object.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a custom exception as per your need.Example of a custom exception.

```
class AmountException implements Exception { 
  String get errorMessage => 'Amount should be greater than zero'; 
}  
void main() { 
  try { 
    withdrawAmount(-1); 
  } catch(e) { 
    print(e.errorMessage); 
  } finally { 
    print('Ending requested operation.....'); 
  } 
}  
void withdrawAmount(int amount) { 
  if (amount <= 0) { 
    throw AmountException(); 
  } 
}
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_exceptions.htm